# SwitUI iOS localization language is not changing

Tags: xcode, swiftui, localization

I localized my app in Xcode 13.2.1 into two languages as shown on picture below - EN texts are hardcoded, CZ texts are in Localizable file (imported from xcloc file).

[image]

App is constantly appearing in CZ in Simulator even if I set EN language in Run scheme. The only way I found so far to change appearence to EN is to remove CZ localization from the app at all. Any hint, please? Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I was able to fix it:

1. Select the `Localizable.strings` file in the project navigator.
2. In the File Inspector, you'll see "English" being unchecked, you need to mark it checked.
3. By default, Xcode will copy an existing non-English localization for English, so we need to replace it with the original English translation. Luckily, it's possible to just extract it from the .xloc package.
4. Select menu Product - Export Localizations, make sure English is checked and run the export.
5. Open the directory of export in Finder, locate the `en.xloc` file. Right click on it and choose "Show package contents".
6. Inside the package, go to `Source Contents/%TargetName%/en.lproj`.
7. Inside, you'll see the `Localizable.strings` file. Copy it into your project, replacing the file that Xcode generated previously.
8. Rebuild the app.

After doing all that, English localization should be back.